# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTravauxInterne.sdloadingTask, int, List<String>) is undefined

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a spinner widget with dynamic data. Firstly, i receive a jsonarray that i break and saved to my model as follows

```
    list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int nombre=0;nombre<nombre_tache;nombre++){


            JSONObject tache= (JSONObject) response.get(nombre);

                tid= tache.getString("tid");
                task= tache.getString("task");

                travauxInterne.add(new TravauxInterne(tid,task));

                list.add(travauxInterne.get(nombre).task.toString());

    }
```

where travauxInterne is a global arraylist

```
ArrayList<TravauxInterne> travauxInterne = new ArrayList<TravauxInterne>();
```

When i set the spinner adapter as follows the error occurs.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and i get the following error:

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(AddTravauxInterne.sdloadingTask, int, List<String>) is undefined
```

Comment: You have not used any of the constructors defined by [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Comment: can you tell me more please

Comment: is AddTravauxInterne.sdloadingTask an Activity context?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing this within your inner AsyncTask so `this` refers to that, which is causing the error.

Change it to:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NameOfYourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```